# Use awk on prose

Tags: awk

I have a sorted list of phrases, list.txt. I want use awk to strip any entry on that list from a lengthy file of prose, and replace it with a return. It's not hard to find examples of using awk to compare two files, but they all assume both are neatly structured, which prose is not.

Here's the relevant part of the script:

```
#! /bin/sh
...

sed '
s/[0-9]/\n/g        # strip out all numbers, replace with returns
s/[@€•\!¡%“”"_–=\*\&\/\?¿\,\.]/\n/g
' $1 > $1.z.tmp

cp stowplist.txt strip1.tmp

awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t" } ; { print $1 }' SpanishGlossary.utf8 >> strip1.tmp
#sh ./awkwords SpanishGlossary.utf8 >> strip1.tmp

sort -u strip1.tmp > strip2.tmp

awk '{ print length(), $0 | "sort -rn" }' strip2.tmp > strip3.tmp
#echo "List ordered by length."

#echo "Now creating new script." # THIS AFFECTS THE SCRIPT, NOT THE OUTPUT FILE.
sed '
s/[0-9]//g      # strip out all numbers
s/[\t^\ *\ $]// # strip tabs, leading and trailing spaces
/^.\{0,5\}$/d       # delete lines with less than five characters
/^$/d           # delete blank lines
s/^/\\y/g           # begin word boundary
s/$/\\y/g           #end word boundary
s/\ /\\ /g      # make spaces into literals
' strip3.tmp > strip.tmp

echo "Eliminating existing entries. This may take a while."
awk 'NR==FNR{p = p s $0; s="|" ;next} {gsub(p,"\n");print}' strip.tmp $1.z.tmp > $1.1.tmp

...
```

And here's a representative sample of strip.tmp:

```
\yinfraestructura\ de\ la\ fabricación\y
\yFecha\ de\ Vencimiento\ del\ Contrato\y
\yfactores\ importantes\ a\ considerar\y
\yexcepto\ lo\ estrictamente\ personal\y
\yexamen\ de\ los\ ojos\ con\ dilatación\y
\yes\ un\ estado\ capitalista\ corrupto\y
\yes\ un\ derecho\ legal\ reconocido\ en\y
\yestimular\ la\ capacidad\ productiva\y
\yestimación\ de\ la\ edad\ gestacional\y
\yEste\ Programa\ de\ Transición\ Verde\y
\yEstán\ permanentemente\ enfrentados\y
```

And finally, a representative sample of the input text, with punctuation substituted with line breaks.

```
Es la historia de más de un siglo del cooperativismo en Argentina
 con empresas en todos los rincones de nuestra geografía y en todos los sectores de la economía

En plena crisis del sistema económico mundial
 con creciente alarma frente al deterioro a escala planetaria de las condiciones medio ambientales
 la comunidad internacional ha declarado
 desde la Organización de las Naciones Unidas
 a éste como el Año Internacional de las Cooperativas

No es casualidad
 el mundo está buscando nuevos caminos
 nuevos paradigmas para organizarse
```

Comment: You just want to delete words from file2 if the words in file1? what is the format of file1? one phrase per line? can you give some input/output example??

Comment: Do phrases from `list.txt` sometimes span multiple lines?  I.e. does the correct solution need to account for a phase that's split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one-liner may work for you:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{p[$0];next}{a[FNR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){for(l in p)gsub(l,"",a[i]);print a[i]}}' file1 file2
```

Note:

```
file1 is your list.txt
file2 is your prose
```

small example:

```
kent$  head file*                                                                                                     
==> file1 <==
good for you
hi there
awk is nice

==> file2 <==
line1 blah (hi there) blah (good for you)
line2 blah (awk is nice) blah (hi there)(good for you)
line3 blah blah (good for you) (awk is nice)(hi there)

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{p[$0];next}{a[FNR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){for(l in p)gsub(l,"",a[i]);print a[i]}}' file1 file2
line1 blah () blah ()
line2 blah () blah ()()
line3 blah blah () ()()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately, and contrary to my expectations, this was far slower than doing the same thing to sed. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: @user1889034 One reason would be that it reads the whole of file 2 into an array and then loops through that array doing the substitutions instead of just doing the substitutions as each line is read. I'll post a couple of alternatives that don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

@Kent posted:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{p[$0];next}{a[FNR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){for(v in p)gsub(v,"",a[i]);print a[i]}}' file1 file2
```

I changed the variable `l` to `v` for readability - never use `l` as a variable name as it looks too much like the number `1`.

The above reads the whole of file2 into an array and then loops through that array doing the substitutions instead of just doing the substitutions as each line is read, e.g.:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{p[$0];next} {for(v in p)gsub(v,"");print}' file1 file2
```

but an even faster alternative is to, instead of building up an array of the phrases you want to remove , just build an RE string so you can do a single gsub() on each line of file2 instead of one gsub() per phrase from file1:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{p = p s $0; s="|" ;next} {gsub(p,"");print}' file1 file2
```

Just be aware with all of those you're doing an RE comparison so RE metacharacters in file1 will make a difference to what matches in file2. Since you're comparing to a sed solution I assume that's fine.

If speed was all you cared about, this GNU awk solution would probably be even faster:

```
$ gawk -v RS='\0' -v FS='\n' -v OFS='|' 'NR==FNR{NF--; p=$0; next} {gsub(p,"");print}' file1 file2
line1 blah () blah ()
line2 blah () blah ()()
line3 blah blah () ()()
```

but it's pretty cryptic, uses more memory than the others, and is not very extensible so I wouldn't bother with it.

I'd use the solution above that build up "p" as a single RE and does a single gsub() on each line.

Comment: What about word boundaries?  Would it be better with `p=" (foo|bar) "`, or `p=" foo | bar "`?

Comment: It's hard to say without some sample input and expected output, but I'd go with something like p="\<(foo|bar)\>" if it's required.

Comment: On word boundaries, I added \y to the beginning and end of each entry in my list file (which is also auto-generated). Additionally, I made the spaces literals, which gave me the expected output, but in far more time. I'm currently testing the third line above. Thanks again!

Comment: Oops. bash killed the process. Did I mention my list has over 50,000 entries? Trying the second one.

Comment: Hmm, bash doesn't typically run around killing processes. Did the script run for a long time? What exactly is your script and how did you run it? What exactly was the result of running the script (output, error message, etc.)? 50,000 entries shouldn't be a problem. Edit your question and copy/paste the script along with the error message, if any, when it died and some sample input and expected output would go a long way...

Comment: Well, now it's not killing the process, with the third one. However, it strips out everything, leaving me with an empty results file. Back to the second one.

Comment: Again, we'd need to see what you're doing to be able to help you, see my previous comment. Also, check (`cat -v`) your input files for control-Ms as provided by Microsoft to corrupt all of your files for you for no aditional charge.

Comment: What are Control-Ms? I did find a bunch of "shy hyphens" that were artifacts of converting from ISO to UFT8.

I did post my script above -- I should have mentioned it. Two other scripts are called from it, but those are behaving as expected.

Comment: Control-Ms are the characters you get when you hold down the control key and M key on your keyboard simultaneously. Windows thinks its cute to insert them before your newline characters so you need to remove them to use UNIX tools on those files. man dos2unix. The awk script you posted can only give you an empty output file if $1.z.tmp is empty or you're using a broken awk (e.g. /usr/bin/awk on Solaris). Don't post all the stuff around it - post the input files (i.e. SAMPLES of strip.tmp and $1.z.tmp), the one awk script you care about and copy/paste what happens when you execute it.

Comment: Files samples added above. At this point, I'm getting the expected results... but after a very long time. Both the second and third lines above take about 460 seconds to run, whereas sed takes about 38.

Comment: beats me, unless all those \y's are having some effect? Why did you replace punctuation with line breaks in your sample input? does any of the text in your second file match the lines from the first file? Why are you escaping spaces in your first file?

Comment: I replace punctuation because I don't want my glossary phrases to include it. There are vanishingly few cases where that would be helpful. And when I simply delete phrases but otherwise leave lines intact, the search ends up taking longer still. Yes, plenty of lines from the first file match phrases in the second -- on the order of 70% of the text file gets eliminated. I escape the spaces because when I didn't, I got garbage. It was apparently strings from within words. ...So, anyway, I've learned a bit about awk, and even integrated it to build my list file. Thanks for your patient help.